# How do I inject certain files into certain websites from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I have multiple files that inject script into websites, I want to know how I can inject 1 file for a certain website. To better explain

My chrome extension has 1 file to inject into [Github](https://github.com) and another file to inject into a different website how would I inject each one into there own website **without** having both files injecting into each website. So each file will be injected into there own website.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script -- Now you just need to figure how to inject a certain script on a certain page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injecting JavaScript files is done either through an entry in the [`content_scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) key in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), or through [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

### Using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`

You should use `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` if you don't need your script injected *every single time* the matching URL is loaded. This is particularly the case when interaction with your extension begins with the user clicking on a [`browserAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), or [`pageAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) button.

Given that `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` is a direct JavaScript API call, I am going to assume that you understand how to make a choice as to what to inject based on the URL from the [`tab.url`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-Tab-url) property.

Injecting *stackContent.js* could look like:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{
    file: "stackContent.js"
}, result => {
    handleExecuteScriptAndInsertCSSErrors(tabId);
});
```

Injecting both *jquery.js* and *stackContent.js* could look like:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{
    file: "jquery.js"
}, result1 => {
    handleExecuteScriptAndInsertCSSErrors(tabId);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{
        file: "stackContent.js"
    }, result2 => {
        handleExecuteScriptAndInsertCSSErrors(tabId);
    });
});
```

You should also be checking for errors reported by [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError).  A function I use for doing so in both Chrome and Firefox WebExtensions is:

```
function handleExecuteScriptAndInsertCSSErrors(tabId) {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        let message = chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
        let isFirefox = !!window.InstallTrigger;
        let extraMessage = tabId ? 'in tab ' + tabId + '.' : 'on this page.';
        if((!isFirefox && message.indexOf('Cannot access a chrome:') > -1) //Chrome
            || (isFirefox && message.indexOf('No window matching') > -1) //Firefox
        ) {
            //The current tab is one into which we are not allowed to inject scripts.
            //  This is most likely because we are injecting based on a action button
            //  click. You should disable the action button when a tab is active on
            //  which you can not perform the task that is expected by the user.
            let messageText= 'This extension, ' + chrome.runtime.id
                             + ', does not work ' + extraMessage;
            //alert(messageText); //Use for testing
            console.log(messageText);
        } else {
            //Report the error
            if(isFirefox) {
                //In Firefox, runtime.lastError is an Error Object including a stack trace.
                console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            } else {
                console.error(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Using the `content_scripts` key in *manifest.json*

In your *manifest.json* you have a `content_scripts` key which describes scripts or CSS that are always injected into matching URLs. You should use this if you need a script, or CSS to be **always** injected into matching URLs.

While it might be more convenient to always have your script injected, you should seriously consider not doing so unless it is *needed*. You should particularly stay away from doing so if you are loading large scripts and/or on a large number of websites (e.g. all URLs). Indiscriminately injecting your script(s) (including libraries) on a large number of websites can take significant resources on the user's computer which can cause a loss of performance, affecting user experience. If you need to have interaction begin from within the website, try loading a smaller script that waits for that interaction to begin, then messages your background script to inject the rest of your functionality. Sometimes you do need your script loaded all the time, but try to think about it from your user's perspective, not just what is convenient in writing your extension. As an example of going too far injecting scripts using `content_scripts`, the extension about which [this question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39054125/3773011) injects 78 different scripts into *every* `https://` page.

The `content_scripts` key contains an array of objects. Each object describes a single injection directive. The object can contain multiple conditions and multiple files, but each one is all-or-nothing; either all files described in that object are injected, or none, depending on if the URL matches. If you want some file(s) injected to some URLs and some other file(s) injected to other URLs, then you use separate Objects to describe each group.

An example, which injects *jquery.js* & *stackContent.js* into Stack Exchange sites and *jquery.js* & *exampleContent.js* into `example.com` is:

```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http*://*.askubuntu.com/*",
            "http*://*.mathoverflow.net/*",
            "http*://*.serverfault.com/*",
            "http*://*.stackapps.com/*",
            "http*://*.stackexchange.com/*",
            "http*://*.stackoverflow.com/*",
            "http*://*.superuser.com/*"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "stackContent.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["http*://*.example.com/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "exampleContent.js"]
    }
]
```

### Permissions

Depending on what you are doing, you are going to need permissions to interact with the matching URLs you are interested in and/or use `chrome.tabs`.  From the above examples:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http*://*.askubuntu.com/*",
    "http*://*.mathoverflow.net/*",
    "http*://*.serverfault.com/*",
    "http*://*.stackapps.com/*",
    "http*://*.stackexchange.com/*",
    "http*://*.stackoverflow.com/*",
    "http*://*.superuser.com/*",
    "http*://*.example.com/*"
]
```

Comment: ok so you can use matches multiple times in the json file. I came here to ask the question after I went to a couple of websites but all the manifest files had 1 matches line so I didnt know if i could do that thanks. Sorry I have a hard time explaining stuff.

Comment: @BannerBomb, No problem. I'm glad I was able to help. Yes, *manifest.json* can have as many objects describing injections as you desire in the `content_scripts` array.

Comment: @BannerBomb, FYI: I'm planning to significantly update/expand the `tabs.executeScript()` section with code that should make using injections which you can turn on and off *much* easier (similar in use to how they are described in *manifest.json*, but with the ability to turn them on and off, or use arbitrary programmatic conditions (e.g. one currently working test case only injects the list of scripts and CSS if turned on and the the minute when the page loads is even)). Should be a day or two. I'll `@BannerBomb` ping you when I update the answer in case it is useful to you.

Comment: ok thanks ------"this is just extra characters because the message needed 6 more to post the comment"-------

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey extensions, with the header like that:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         MTV Statistical Data For Tampermonkey & Greasemonkey
// @namespace    MTV_statistical_data
// @include     /^https?://(www\.)?mytrafficvalue\.com/shareholders\.html(\#marketplace)?$/
// @author       facebook.com/igor39
// @version      7.5
// @grant        none
// @description  Improving the user experience & provide more of statistics on the page www.mytrafficvalue.com/shareholders.html
// ==/UserScript==
```

Example: http://pastebin.com/Z4zq2h6Q

Comment: While this is a method of injecting a script into a webpage, it does not address the actual question, which was how to inject scripts from within a Chrome extension which the OP is writing.